# flutter inspector : I don't want a popup

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, inspector

[image]

I am using android studio.

Every time I click a widget in the inspector window, a popup pops up, which is very annoying.

Please tell me how to disable popup.

Comment: This is devTool , try closing it

Comment: I would like to see the structure of the widget with devtool. But I hate to see that popup.

Comment: uncheck the top left icon

Answer (score 0):

To disable focusing on widget tree uncheck this

[image]

Uncheck on `Open Flutter Inspector view on app launch`

[image]

Comment: That item is already unchecked...

Comment: Can you share your setting ss, or match with mine

Answer (score 0):

One of the options is disabled JxBrowser... Preferences > Languages & Frameworks > Flutter uncheck "Enable embedding DevTools in the Flutter Inspector tool window". After that another browser will be used. Icons will be different but the essence remains the same...
[image]